# pd.to_datetime() Stop to working, application crash

Tags: python, django, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dashboard that use pandas to manipulate datas, and my DateTime conversions are being performed by pd.to_datetime function as sample below:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1['ProcessFinishTime'],errors='ignore')
```

I never had any problems related to dates in pandas.

However today morning tried run my app and face this error message:

```
raise TypeError(f"dtype {data.dtype} cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]")
TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

O tried to use the function below, but without success.

```
pd.to_datetime(df1['ProcessFinishTime'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

Comment: How working `pd.to_datetime(df1['ProcessFinishTime'],errors='coerce')` ? Problem is if use `ignore` it working like if some non datetimelike value converting nothing.

Comment: Do you mind to add `df1.info()` before the conversion?

Comment: What is the type of the values in df1['ProcessFinishTime']? What you get using df1['ProcessFinishTime'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]', copy=True)? Look at this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html, (.to_pydatetime), it may be helpful.

Comment: @jezrael i tried 'coerce' it returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

So after a while I understood that you wanted to extract the number of hours from a series of timedelta.

Try `(series / pd.Timedelta('1H')).astype(int)`

This gives you the number of hours in `series` and casts it to `int`

*PS: Please put a more explicit title so people can understand what you want.*

Comment: O tied pd.Timestamp but not working and returning error message ```TypeError: Cannot convert input [0       0```

Comment: @CaioEuzébio Do you understand the difference between a time delta and an absolute time ?

Comment: i never use before, but i will try.

Comment: @CaioEuzébio https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html. You don't need to convert it, what you want is timedelta, not datetime.

Comment: Not worked, it returns a error message. ``` TypeError: Cannot convert input [0 ```.

Comment: @CaioEuzébio I don't even know what you are trying to do. Why are you not happy with these timedelta ?

Comment: Because with timedelta my application crash, with opandas i use a lambda function to get a hour for some oprations, sample if in column A row 1 the time is 13:01:01, i have a column that isolate thius hour 13. With timedelta its not possible.

Comment: What is this series supposed to contain ?

Comment: pd.to_timedelta ?

Comment: Yes, i have times in format '13:01:01', and with timedelta i cant isolate only '13'.

Comment: Yes, it converts columns in pandas Series not timestamp with not allow extract .hour() from column.

Comment: i using(    df1['ProcessStartTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['ProcessStartTime'])   )

Comment: You should have told that you wanted the hour. I put the answer.

Comment: Not worked as expected. Why pd.to_datetime() work correctly in ubunto but not in macos?